# Using factory method for creating common Mockito stubbings in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In project I am working on we have a bunch of commonly used helpers. Consider the following example:

```
public class ServiceHelper {
    public HttpServletRequest() getRequest() { ... }
    public Model getModel() { ... }
    public UserCache getUserCache() { ... }
    public ComponentContainer getComponentContainer() { ... }
}
```

Imagine this helper is being used across the whole application by every web service we have. Then, in order to test these services I need to mock it. Each time. But what if I create a factory of some kind instead, something like:

```
public class ServiceHelperMockStore {

  public static ServiceHelper create() {
    return init();
  }

  public static ServiceHelper create(final Model model) {
    final ServiceHelper helper = init();
    when(helper.getModel()).thenReturn(model);
    return helper;
  }

  private static ServiceHelper init() {
    final ServiceHelper helper = mock(ServiceHelper.class);

    final HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    final Model model = mock(Model.class);
    final UserCache userCache = mock(UserCache.class);
    final ComponentContainer container = mock(ComponentContainer.class);
    final BusinessRules businessRules= mock(BusinessRules.class);
    final ModelTransformer modelTransformer = mock(ModelTransformer.class);

    when(helper.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
    when(helper.getModel()).thenReturn(model);
    when(helper.getUserCache()).thenReturn(userCache);
    when(helper.getComponentContainer()).thenReturn(container);
    when(container.getComponent(BusinessRules.class)).thenReturn(businessRules);
    when(componentContainer.getComponent(ModelTransformer.class)).thenReturn(modelTransformer);

    return helper;
  }
}
```

This factory nicely fit my purposes and oftentimes I can completely avoid using 'mock' and 'when' in the actual test suites. Instead, I can do the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ModelServiceTest {

  private final Model model = new Model();
  private final ServiceHelper serviceHelper = ServiceHelperMockStore.create(model);
  private final BusinessRules businessRules = serviceHelper.getComponentContainer().getComponent(BusinessRules.class);

  private final ModelType modelType1 = new ModelType();
  private final ModelType modelType2 = new ModelType();

  private final ModelService modelService = new ModelService(serviceHelper);

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    modelType1.setItemId("item1");
    modelType2.setItemId("item2");
    model.setTypes(modelType1, modelType2);
    when(businessRules.get("type")).thenReturn(modelType1);
  }

  ...tests...
}
```

So instead of creating a lot of mocks in the ModelServiceTest, I can just access the predefined ones, like:

```
BusinessRules businessRules = serviceHelper.getComponentContainer().getComponent(BusinessRules.class);
```

and this even reflect my helper's API. Also, I can provide my own mock or stub passing parameters to my factory method or using some different approach.

The only problem I have is **UnnecessaryStubbingException** being thrown by Mockito as normally I don't use all those stubbings I've created per each test file. So I have to use *MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent* runner to silent the error and according to the [mockito api docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.26/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.html) it is not recommended.

So I am seeking for an advice what kind of approach must be chosen in this case. Am I doing it right or there is some other way? Or, maybe, using such kind of factories is a bad style of programming in relation to unit tests as it hides some initialization and makes happening things less evident so I must do just a plain copy of my code between test suits?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need this identical complex mock configuration at different places shows that your code violates the *Law of Demeter* (Don't talk to strangers).

A unit should only get dependencies it actually interacts with (other than  only to getting another dependency from it).

---

> So instead of creating a lot of mocks in the ModelServiceTest, I can just access the predefined ones,

You Unittests are not only *verification of correct behavior* but also *minimal examples how to use the CUT* (Code under test).

The configuration of the CUTs dependencies is an essential part of that example and should be easily accessible to the reader of the tests.

I'd strongly discourage from "factories for mocks" especially it they were moved to other classes (in the `test` folder).